# CRM 2011: Email "Global Template" only shows Data Fields for "User" only

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, entity, insert-update, email-templates

I'm creating an e-mail template in CRM 2011. I chose "Global Template" and clicked on "Insert/Update" button and the "Record Type" list only showed "User". I need to add fields for other entities as well. Any idea why is it limited to User only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Global Template is limited to inserting fields from the `SystemUser` record of the sender.

Why? Because it is a global template that is the only record is guaranteed to be available when the template is used, since there will always a be a From User - no other entity is universally required for all emails.

There is no e-mail template that supports fields on a custom entity. You would have to manually implement such functionality.